# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a function as defined below:

```
def season_map(x):
    return x.map({1:'spring',2:'summer',3:'fall',4:'winter'})
```

Now on calling the function on season column which only contains values 1, 2, 3 or 4:

```
bike_data['season'] = bike_data['season'].apply(season_map)
```

The error given is:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'map'

But if I try:

```
bike_data['season'] = bike_data['season'].map({1:'spring',2:'summer',3:'fall',4:'winter'})
```

It works perfectly!

Unable to understand what is the difference in the 2 approaches apart from syntax....

Answer (score 1):

My first answer/post.
I was solving this problem today.
The answer is you need to pass the particular column as a list:

```
    def season_map(x):
        return x.map({1:'spring',2:'summer',3:'fall',4:'winter'})
    bike_data[['season']] = bike_data[['season']].apply(season_map)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The map function gets the integer, but has a map as well. Probably just a copy paste error.

Try

```
def season_map(x):
    return {1:'spring', 2:'summer', 3:'fall', 4:'winter'}[x]
```

Or easier

```
season_map = {1:'spring', 2:'summer', 3:'fall', 4:'winter'}
bike_data['season'] = bike_data['season'].map(season_map)
```